# Different checksum for Pop OS 20.04 iso

Tags: checksum, pop-os

I'm trying to install Pop OS (no NVIDIA). I have downloaded several times and always the checksum SHA256 is different that the checksum they show in their website.

The SHA256 in Pop OS website for iso 20.04 LTS is:

```
SHA256 Sum:
68ffcb9d131ff554bfb68abd3956b0a6f6eafec497bdae5581bd5341a6dd2b98
```

and when I downloaded and verify SHA256 I get this one:

```
dd15fc489ab12b215de52a16df2cccbd77ca50d4aec0c3f379d8de35dc9cf824
```

And when I try to run/install that iso in VirtualBox or VMware I get error below:

```
SOLINUX 6.04 EDD 20190226 EHDD Copyright (C) 1994-2015 H. Peter Anvin et al

Failed to load ldlinux.c32
Boot failed: press a key to retry... I
```

So, it seems the ISO is corrupt.

How to fix this, or can be downloaded from other side? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have this issue myself but some others did and fixed it by changing their dns to Cloudflare's ones (1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1) or any others (Quad9 ones for example if you prefer security/privacy over speed: 9.9.9.9 and 149.112.112.112), then retry.

It could be due to outdated checksum after an update, which should be only temporary in this case as System76 will correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried as you say and it worked. I tried with Tor Browser and worked too.